# Singleton VS static(class) variables

Tags: ios, swift, macos

What is the best practice in Swift?

**Option 1:**

```
class SomeManager {

    static var sharedManager = SomeManager()

    var someVariable: String?

}
```

and then

```
let something = SomeManager.sharedManager().someVariable
```

**Option 2:**

```
class SomeManager {

    static var someVariable: String?

}
```

and then

```
let something = SomeManager.someVariable
```

Comment: The best practice in my opinion is t use the singleton approach, because then you can initialise other instances of that class without any shared data among them. While this might not be required, just having this option indicates a cleaner design.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### tl;dr

Option 1 (class or struct) when you store mutable state because you need other instances.

Option 2 (scoped global variables) when you want to store static variables because it's faster and uses less memory.

#### Singleton Class (or struct) with variables

Global state is generally considered a "bad thing". It's hard to think about, causes problems but is sometimes unavoidable.

- Create a class if you ever want to have multiple `SomeManager` instances.
- A singleton can be good default instance but there may be edge cases where you want to have separate behavior (testing).
- Dependency Injection... is big topic that is relevant if `SomeManager` is storing global state.

#### Static Variable

- Always use when the `someVariable` is a constant.
- Does not require extra storage for `static var sharedManager = SomeManager()`; you use only the memory which you actually need.
- Slightly faster because you do not need to load `sharedManager` into memory then access it's member `someVariable`. You straight up access `someVariable`.

#### Bonus Tip:

In Option 2 you can create `SomeManager` even though it doesn't do anything. You can prevent this by turning `SomeManager` into an enum with no cases.

```
enum SomeManager {
    static var someVariable: String?
}
```

You can still do this:

```
SomeManager.someVariable
```

but you can't do this

```
let manager = SomeManger()
```

Comment: Regarding the bonus tip, you could actually do this by implementing a private init. This is actually something you should do for either option. Just add `private init() {}`.

Comment: I didn't realize that, thanks